# Prove $g(x)= x^2 \sin \left(\frac1x\right)$ is not uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Prove $g(x)= \{x^2 \sin \left(\frac1x\right);x\neq 0$  and $g(0)=0$

is not uniformly continuous

so I know g is continuous at $0$. However, I think $g$ isn't uniformly continuous based on the graph. I thinking I want to find a cauchy sequence that $g$ doesn't preserve.
Another option would be to find two sequences that converge, but whose images don't.

Comment: If you find a Cauchy Sequence the image of which is not Cauchy (hence does not converge) the function would fail to be continuous. Same about the two sequences (what is the difference, actually?)

Comment: I saw an example with $sin(x^2)$ where $sqrt(2n \pi)$ and $ sqrt(2n \pi + \pi/2)$ have the same limit but their images don't, which shows $sin(x^2)$ isnt uniformly continuous

Comment: Hmm? Both sequences go off to infinity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $g$ is continuous. Therefore it is uniformly continuous on any compact set.

Now consider the interval $[1,\infty)$. The derivative is

$$g'(x) = 2x\sin\left(\frac1{x}\right) - \cos\left(\frac1{x}\right).$$

Then

$$|g'(x)| \leq 2\left|x\sin\left(\frac1{x}\right)\right| + \left|\cos\left(\frac1{x}\right)\right| \leq 2\left|x\sin\left(\frac1{x}\right)\right|+1.$$

Note that for $0 \leq y \leq 1$,

$$\left|\frac{\sin\left(y\right)}{y}\right|\leq 1.$$

Hence for $x \geq 1$,

$$\left|x\sin\left(\frac1{x}\right)\right|= \left|\frac{\sin\left(\frac1{x}\right)}{\frac1{x}}\right| \leq 1.$$

Therefore

$$|g'(x)| \leq 2\left|x\sin\left(\frac1{x}\right)\right|+1 \leq 3.$$

Since $g$ has a bounded derivative on $[1,\infty)$ it is *uniformly continuous* there.

Make a similar argument for $(-\infty,-1]$. Then it is easy to show that $g$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbf{R} = (-\infty,-1] \cup [-1,1] \cup [1,\infty).$

Answer (score 1):

A continuous function on a metric space is uniformly continuous on any compact subset of the domain. It follows that what's really at issue is what happens as $x$ goes *away* from zero.

As $x \to \infty$, we have $x \sin(1/x) \to 1$, so when $x$ gets large, $g(x)$ becomes arbitarily close to the identity function $f(x) = x$. And $f$ *is* uniformly continuous, so your $g$ must be too.

Comment: His function is $x^2\sin(1/x)$.

Comment: Yes. Yes it is.

Comment: To be clear, my answer, though nowhere near as complete as the other one, does not misread the question.